# No init start up error

Tags: 10.10, boot, grub2, startup

I'm running Ubuntu on a dual boot with Windows Vista, I've just gone to boot up as usual in to Ubuntu and I have this error

```
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

Busybox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5) built-in shell
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

This happens after I select Ubuntu from the Grub menu,

any help would be great. :)

Comment: - Have you got another kernel installed or just this one?
  
- Did you make any upgrades before rebooting?  

- Have you got a Live CD in order to do a chrooted update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot into the live CD and try repairing it with the following command:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

The `sda1` might be vary for you sometimes.If you are not sure on the name of your drive then run gparted.It should list the name of the drive.Just replace the sda1 with the name of your drive. Let me know if this helps you. :)

You can boot into a rescue console by starting your computer from a live cd and selecting "Rescue a broken system" from the menu.

Comment: ok I'm running live right now and this is the output from that command "fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2
Could this be a zero-length partition?"

Comment: Can you post the output's of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2964f869
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       20615   165581789+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           20615       38914   146988033    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           20615       38166   140978176   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           38166       38914     6008832   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Its not 1 its small L. `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16000221184 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1945 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000df657

Comment: yeh sorry just saw :P , that is the output in 2 parts as it was too long

Comment: although just reading the 16 gb last part must be the USB key im running live from

Comment: Paste your whole output in paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link

Comment: ah I forgot about that! http://paste.ubuntu.com/540749/

Comment: In your case run the following `sudo fsck /dev/sda5`

Comment: ah just saw my drive name was sda5 from the post before so I ran that and it gave me fix options

Comment: so now i have this http://paste.ubuntu.com/540750/

Comment: Probably you have fixed all the errors.Reboot your system and see if you get rid of that error.

Comment: that fixed it! :) thanks for your time guys great stuff

Comment: fsck doesn't work.  my partition is clean

Comment: @jimmy-phucker What's your problem..Write a new question describing your problem..