# Booting ubuntu gives "init not found"

Tags: boot, init, fsck

My friend has been using ubuntu 10.10 on vmware player for many days now. But today, it has a problem booting, so we started the ubuntu live cd to try and fix it.

Running `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` (got from [No init start up error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16562/no-init-start-up-error)) says that the `device or resouce busy`. So, I'm guessing the partition was not unmounted correctly on the last shutdown for some reason.

Any help on how to fix the problem would be appreciated. If you need any further information, please provide the command to get it, as we have little knowledge of that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem. It seems that recent ubuntu livecds have the bad behaviour to access the disk partitions at startup, and make them busy if they are not fsck clean.

The solution I found was to run the fsck on that partition starting with a different diagnostic livecd, in particular I used [finnix](http://www.finnix.org/releases/101/finnix-101.iso), a Debian derivative.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. we'll try it out and let you know.