# Ubuntu not booting with a missing /sbin/init

Tags: mount, fsck

Linux/Ubuntu noob here and my installation just choked with the `/sbin/init` error.

This is similar to this previous issue: [Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/days-old-but-wont-boot-missing-sbin-init-help)

And this [link](http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html) describes the apparent solution.

I have a dual boot eepc 1001px, my partitions are a little different, `fdisk -l` gives me:

```
/dev/sda1 * ID=7 HPFS/NFFS
/dev/sda2   ID=lb Hidden w95 FAT32
/dev/sda3   ID=5 Extended
/dev/sda4   ID=ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda5   ID=83 Linux
```

I'm using a bootable usb key with the netbook 10.10 version installed so I can get into Ubuntu that way for diagnostics.

I tried the `sudo fsck /dev/sda5` as mentioned in the second link to attempt a repair however I get the following error:

```
fsck.ext4: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda5
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?
```

And I've no idea what to do next :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a look at this answer [Booting ubuntu gives "init not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34999/booting-ubuntu-gives-init-not-found/35000#35000)