# Kernel panic /dev/sda: clean

Tags: kernel, 16.04, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu/windows 10 dual boot. I've installed the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit to use GPU version of TensorFlow. After rebooting it, it got stuck at 
/dev/sda6: clean,..... for a very long time and the laptop was out of charge.

After I plugged in and turned it on, it got stuck at this point as shown in the image:

[image: Kernel panic]

Comment: Check this: [Booting ubuntu gives "init not found"](http://askubuntu.com/a/35000)

Comment: But to run fsck,I've to open terminal right? But i can't open it unless i logon

Comment: You'd need to run it from a live USB / DVD.

Comment: Does that lead to any data loss??

Comment: No, running fsck from a live USB won't result in data loss.

Comment: it didn't work! -.-